# Should I inject "child" dependencies into my client?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have two services: service A and service B.

Service A depends on service B, therefore I inject service B into service A.

Now I need to use service A in my controller. I just need to call a method in service A, not in service B.

**What is the best practice in dependency injection?**

Should I just inject service A into my controller, because I only need to call a method in service A and not in service B?

Or should I inject both service A and service B into my controller, because I need to be explicit and advertise all the dependencies of my controller?

Answer (score 2):

There is no one-size-fits-all solution.

However, if you're using a dependency resolver, (A DI-container) you should ask that resolver for the instance you need. The resolver should then also resolve its dependencies.

If not, I'd be inclined to inject both A and B.